# Is enumerateUsingBlock: thread safe?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, foundation

Is enumerateUsingBlock: thread safe? I mean, can I mutate an NSMutableArray while enumerating it using enumerateUsingBlock on another thread?

How about enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock: when using NSEnumerationConcurrent option?

Comment: Rule #1 of thread safety: If you have to ask, it isn't thread-safe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `NSMutableArray` is never intrinsically thread safe. All enumeration assumes the collection remains unmodified, including `NSEnumerationConcurrent`. If you modify the collection during an enumeration, even from the same thread, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking that to be the case. I was just confused by the fact that it is possible to enumerate items concurrently.

Comment: You'll note that all the enumeration methods are defined on the immutable superclass. There are many cases where you would enumerate an array (serially or concurrently) and not modify it. Mutating an array you're currently enumerating is, at best, a delicate proposition, and IME usually constitutes "bad code smell."